# If $p \in U\subseteq M$ is an open subset, then $C^\infty_p(U) = C^\infty_p(M)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, germs

Let $M$ be a (smooth) manifold and $p \in M$. We define $C^\infty_p(M)$ to be the set of equivalence classes of smooth functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$ that are identified when they agree on some  neighborhood of $p$.

In Tu's book "Introduction to manifolds", p87, I read that if $U$ is an open subset of $M$ containing $p$, then
$$C_p^\infty(M) = C_p^\infty(U)$$

**Questions**: Evidently, this is not a strict equality because on the right we have (classes of) functions $U \to \mathbb{R}$ and on the left we have functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$. Hence, I guess that they mean that there is a canonical isomorphism (of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras)
$$C_p^\infty(M) \to C_p^\infty(U): f \mapsto f\vert_U$$

Clearly this is injective, because if $f$ and $g$ agree on $U$, then they are in the same class so $f= g$ in $C_p^\infty(M)$. Why is this mapping surjective? Don't we need that a smooth function $U \to \mathbb{R}$ can be smoothly extended to a smooth function $M \to \mathbb{R}$ for this?

Comment: That's not the same definition as Tu uses, unless I'm misremembering. An element of $C_p^{\infty}(U)$ is an equivalence class of tuples $(f,V)$ where  $V$ is an open neigborhood of $p$ and $f$ is a smooth function on $V$, so germs need not be represented by globally defined functions, a priori (a fortiori, they are, precisely, because of the final fact you quote). The equality is still just a canonical isomorphism, but for much more trivial reasons.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks. I was misunderstanding the definition. But I think the definition I was using is equivalent?

Comment: @Thorgott So actually the canonical isomorphism should be $[(V,f)] \mapsto [(V\cap U, f\vert_{U \cap V})]$

Comment: Yes, the definitions are equivalent, that's precisely because of the bump function trick in the answer are equivalent. However, the definition as in Tu is the "better" one, because it generalizes (e.g. if you ever learn complex manifolds, it will not be true anymore that any holomorphic germ comes from a globally defined function). You are correct about what the canonical isomorphism looks like.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks for he help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. However, germs are local, so pick a chart inside $U$ containing $p$, so that via a diffeomorphism with euclidean space you obtain a bump function $b : M \to \Bbb R$. Multiplying $f$ with $b$ may not be equal to $b$, but $f$ and $bf$ coincide near $p$ and thus they are equal as germs.